# How to associate iTunes to an existing library after installing Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, itunes

I had Windows XP, installed on my C: drive, and my iTunes library was on the E: drive. I've now replaced XP with Windows 7, so any iTunes settings that were in the registry or its Program Files folder have been lost. I still have all the mp3s and the iTunes Library files on my E: drive, however.

I've installed iTunes on Windows 7, set the "iTunes Media folder location" to E:\iTunes in the Preferences, but I don't have anything appearing in iTunes. Is there a magic step I'm missing, or do I have to "re-create" my library?

(I know I probably should have done something sensible like used iTunes on XP to back up my library, but I just wasn't thinking.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while double clicking on icon to launch iTunes.  You will be prompted to create a new library or choose an existing one. Point to your existing iTunes library (`.itl` file)

Comment: Yeah! Perfect. Out of interest, is this documented anywhere? If not, how are mere mortals supposed to know about it, and if so, why isn't this feature available from a menu in the program??

Comment: "is this documented anywhere" - Apple's KB mentions it http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1589 I found this out because couple weeks ago I faced the same problem and reached there after some googling!

"Why isn't this feature available from a menu" 
- No idea. Apple, erm, you know *Thinks Different*

Comment: alt/option if you're on a mac

Comment: When I follow these steps, nothing happens. The "intro screen" remains and my old library doesn't show up. iTunes appears to pick up my old itl file, but my music doesn't show.

Comment: I had to do the same thing this weekend. Thanks for the answer and Apple link!